# Contact explosion of nitrogen triiodide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, phase, explosives

Nitrogen triiodide, on slightest physical contact, explodes to evolve dense purple fumes of iodine. Why does this phenomenon occur?

video link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KlAf936E90

Comment: Big  badda  boom!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_triiodide) states

> The instability of $\ce{NI3}$ and $\ce{NI3 · NH3}$ can be attributed to the large steric strain caused by the three large iodine atoms being held in close proximity to each other around the relatively tiny nitrogen atom. This results in a very low activation energy for its decomposition, a reaction made even more favorable due to the great stability of $\ce{N2}$.

The steric strain between the atoms can be better visualized by the representations [here](http://www.acornusers.org/education/Thesis/NI3andAgar.html).

The decomposition reaction is
$$\ce{2NI3\to N2 + 3I2}$$
Note that there is an increase in the number of moles (4 versus 2), which means that the reaction is favored by entropy, because there are more possible microstates.

More specifically, the [enthalpy of formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation) is 154.4 kJ/mol, which is incredibly favorable for a reaction.

Reference: [UC Davis ChemWiki](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Development_Details/Approaches/VVV_Demos/Additional_Demos/Nitrogen_Triiodide)

Comment: You might want to add the equation for decomposition.  Since only elements are formed upon decomposition - and they have a heat of formation of zero - the full 154 kJ/mol is released upon decomposition.  Further, 2 moles of product are formed per mole reactant, so the reaction is also entropically driven.

Comment: @ron I should have included the latter information, as I saw it in the link. I'll also include the reaction.

Comment: Also - depending on the particle size of the iodine and how long it is allowed to react with the ammonium hydroxide  before washing the filtrate can result in less than a 100% yield, so some elemental iodine can be left. Upon detonation of the nitrogen tri-iodide the elemental iodine can be vaporized.

Answer (score 0):

HDE 226868's answer covers pretty much about the thermodynamic property of nitogen triiodide, my answer just points out another point, its composition.

Quoting from *Weller, M.; Overton, T.; Rourke, J.; Armstrong, F. Inorganic Chemistry, 6th ed:-*

> Although the formula of nitrogen triiodide is usually written as $\ce{NI3}$, it would be more accurate to write $\ce{I3N}$, as the compound is thought to consist of $\ce{I+}$ and $\ce{N^3-}$ ions and its sensitivity to shock is due to redox instability of these ions. The instability is also due to the combination of a large anion and a small cation.

So, in general if a cation is small and anion is big, lattice enthalpy  increases and decomposition is more likely to be favorable. Detail explanation of the mechanism of contact explosion is [given  in this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33704/mechanism-of-initiation-in-contact-explosives/33714#33714).