# Is Tollen's test safe?

Tags: safety, stability, explosives

Tollen's test is an important test to distinguish between aldehyde and ketone.

$$\ce{2 [Ag(NH3)2]+ + RCHO + H2O → 2 Ag(s) + 4 NH3 + RCO2H + 2 H+}$$

But is this reaction safe? Is there any threat in the formation of [silver nitride (fulminating silver)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_nitride)? It is formed when the products of most of the reaction of silver($\ce{I}$) salts are kept aside undisturbed. It act as a potential explosive or a  [contact explosive](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34178/contact-explosion-of-nitrogen-triiodide). If there is any threat in the formation of silver nitride, what precaution must be taken to prevent it?

Comment: Great question - In general I'd say that not enough attention is given to safety. A good chemist has a plan to dispose of excess reagents as well as the various waste reaction products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tollen's test is safe, but silver amine solutions should be prepared as needed just before use.  The formation of explosive silver nitride is a slow process and can be prevented by treating the solution with mineral acid after use.

Comment: I agree, but it would be nice if you add an equation or link and elaborate a little

Comment: [See here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/145848/disposal-of-silver-halides-dissolved-in-ammonium-hydroxide/145849#145849) for a more detailed answer.