# Mirror reaction - avoiding silver nitride

Tags: safety, silver

I am interested in experimenting with depositing silver on glass (mirror). I've read several papers and watched youtube videos but wish to be better informed about the risk of explosion. The mixture is silver nitrate solution, sodium hydroxide solution, ammonium hydroxide and dextrose solution. Is there a combination, or concentration of any of these that forms silver nitride in less than 3 hours? One video suggested heating the mixture to enhance the deposition onto microscope slides, but neglected to mention a temperature, or whether it hastens the formation of the explosive silver nitride. Any comments on whether $\mathrm{50^oC}$ for 1 hour would have ample margin of safety? Thanks!

Comment: Very related:  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43441/is-tollens-test-safe

Comment: Also keep in mind that even though not all errors will not be explosive, the reaction demands very careful handling, of more than 40 people only 2 of them were able to deposit silver as mirror in my organic chemistry laboratory, others just gave precipitation.